Can I add Privacy Manifest to FBSDK 16.x.x?
We are implementing login using Facebook SDK.
This time, due to the Limited Login issue, I would like to maintain version 16.x.x but only add the Privacy Manifest file. Is that even possible? If possible, can you tell me how to do it?
I want to add Privacy Manifest file to Facebook SDK version 16.x.x.

Unfortunately, you can't, it was published since 17.0.0, you can check the CHANGELOG.MD. So you need to upgrade your current version.
